# Keyboard doesn't appear when first click on UITableViewCell in grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm developing an application in iOS6 and i'm using XCode 4.5.2.

I've a **UITableView** which style is `grouped`. Every single cell has a **UITextField** which size is exactly equal to **UITableViewCell** size. To create **UITextField**, i'm using this piece of code.

```c
  UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 320, 44)];
  txtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ;
  txtField.opaque = 1.0;
  txtField.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
  if(indexPath.row == 0)
      txtField.placeholder = @"Name";
  else if(indexPath.row == 1)
      txtField.placeholder = @"Email";
   if(indexPath.section == 2)
       txtField.placeholder = @"Write here...";
   [cell addSubview:txtField ];
```

And i'm adding this **UITextField** to `cell` as a subview. The problem is that sometimes, when i clicked on the cell, keyboard is supposed to show up. But,here is the screenshot when i clicked on any of cell.[image: Screenshot when clicked on cell]

It means that when i add **UITextField** to a `cell`, it has no effect. Because, it's the normal behaviour of the **UITableView**. The weird issue is that when i clicked on one more times, the keyboard appears, and it's working as it should. But, there is still blue color on the each cell, i can't get it destroyed. Here is the second screenshot.
[image: Screenshot on second times]

And,also it doesn't happen always, so i'm not able to detect what causes this unexpected behaviour.

Do you guys have any idea how can i resolve this problem and what causes it ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you just need to set tableView.allowsSelection to FALSE.

Comment: Wouw, it worked like a charm. I didn't think it would be that easy.Add your comment as an answer,i 'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to set tableView.allowsSelection to FALSE.